# Table updating with same value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

A table, called TBL_stay within a MYSQL database I am using is intended to take the entrance and exit times of vehicles by number plate. resulting in a table in the following format:

```
ID| Plate | Date_in | Time_in | Date_out | Time_out
```

Vehicles are entered into the database from another table, being used as a buffer.
The Entrance date is being transferred into the new table just fine with no problems, because a simple INSERT command is being used. However the exit data is not updating quite how I would like it.

I have to use an update command to make sure the data doesn't get pasted onto a new row, and rather than updating the latest entrance data with the latest exit data, the command I have used instead updates each entrance data entry with only the first result. I'm not sure why this is. please can you help me?

here's the update command for the exit data:

```
update tbl_stay 
join tblout_buffer 
on tblout_buffer.plate=tbl_stay.plate 
set tbl_stay.date_out=tblout_buffer.Date_out, tbl_stay.time_out=tblout_buffer.time_out 
where tbl_stay.date_in=tblout_buffer.date_out
```

the buffers both have the same structure: `Plate | Date In/out | Time In/out`

Here's an example of the situation, for a single plate:

IN Buffer:

```
HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 06-07-08
HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 07-08-09
HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 11-25-45
```

OUT Buffer:

```
HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 06-34-12
HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 10-29-40
HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 16-32-14
```

TBL_STAY:

```
1 |HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 06-07-08 | 2013-12-03 | 06-34-12
2 |HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 07-08-09 | 2013-12-03 | 06-34-12
3 |HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 11-25-45 | 2013-12-03 | 06-34-12
```

but what I want to achieve is:

```
1 |HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 06-07-08 | 2013-12-03 | 06-34-12
2 |HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 07-08-09 | 2013-12-03 | 10-29-40
3 |HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 11-25-45 | 2013-12-03 | 16-32-14
```

---

## UPDATE

The solution posted by Strawberry is a big step in the right direction, however, the process of getting data into the table, as well as another active query on this table causes some interference with this solution:

When a number plate is detected entering the premises, the plate, date & time gets loaded into the `tblin_buffer`. which then gets inserted into the `Plate| Date_in|Time_in|` Columns in `tbl_stay` with an insert command.

A Query, running every few seconds through a VB.net GUI, produces a "Vehicles on site" table by looking for entries in `tbl_stay` that have a `date_in` and `time_in` but do not have a value in `date_out` and `time_out`

When a number plate is detected exiting the premises, the plate, date and time get loaded into the `tblout_buffer`, then the date & time transferred into the `|Date_out|Time_out|` columns of `tbl_stay` with an `update` command.

The insert and update commands trigger each time a plate is detected entering and exiting so ideally, they should only focus on the most recent entries of their respective tables.

While I accept that concatenating date and time may streamline procedures, but I would ideally like to keep the current columns as is, as these are references such in all of the other queries and commands.

some new code samples below, if they help:

Original insert command:

```
insert into 
tbl_stay (Plate,Date_in,Time_in) 
select Plate,Date_in,Time_in 
from tblin_buffer 
where not exists 
(select * from tbl_stay where 
(tblin_buffer.Plate=tbl_stay.plate and tblin_buffer.Date_in=tbl_stay.Date_in and tblin_buffer.Time_in=tbl_stay.Time_in))
```

new insert command, adapted from Strawberry's solution ( currently seems to insert all rows from buffer. tried to compensate for this with the "where not exists clause above, as well as specifying plate values manually):

```
insert into tbl_stay (Plate,date_in,time_in,rank_in)
SELECT   a.plate, a.date_in, a.time_in,rank 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.plate, x.date_in, x.time_in, COUNT(*) rank FROM tblin_buffer x 
         JOIN tblin_buffer y 
          ON y.plate = x.plate 
         AND ((y.date_in < x.date_in) OR (y.date_in = x.date_in AND y.time_in <= x.time_in)) 
       GROUP BY x.plate, x.date_in, x.time_in) a
```

new Update command, also adapted from strawberry's solution:

```
update tbl_stay
JOIN 
( SELECT x.plate
    , x.date_out
    , x.time_out
    , COUNT(*) rank 
FROM tblout_buffer x 
JOIN tblout_buffer y 
    ON y.plate = x.plate 
    AND ((y.date_out < x.date_out) OR (y.date_out = x.date_out AND y.time_out <= x.time_out)) 
GROUP 
    BY x.plate
    , x.date_out
    , x.time_out
) b
ON b.plate = tbl_stay.plate 
AND b.rank = tbl_stay.rank_in
set tbl_stay.date_out=b.date_out,
tbl_stay.time_out=b.time_out,
tbl_stay.rank_out=b.rank;
```

Comment: It is impossible to match the first record from table1 to the first record from table2 etc. using this join condition: `tblout_buffer.plate=tbl_stay.plate`. You must extend `tblout_buffer` table with additional unique field that will contain a record number (1,2,3 etc) and use this field in a join condition. The table `tbl_stay` also has to have unique identifier to perform such update (I assume that the table structure has already some unique identifier - ID column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IN_Buffer;

CREATE TABLE IN_Buffer
(plate VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL,time TIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(plate,date,time)
);

INSERT INTO IN_Buffer VALUES
('HN51KTG','2013-12-03','06:07:08'),
('HN51KTG','2013-12-03','07:08:09'),
('HN51KTG','2013-12-03','11:25:45');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OUT_Buffer;

CREATE TABLE OUT_Buffer
(plate VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL,time TIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(plate,date,time)
);

INSERT INTO OUT_Buffer VALUES
('HN51KTG','2013-12-03','06:34:12'),
('HN51KTG','2013-12-03','10:29:40'),
('HN51KTG','2013-12-03','16:32:14');


SELECT a.plate
     , a.date date_in
     , a.time time_in 
     , b.date date_out
     , b.time time_out
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.plate
            , x.date
            , x.time
            , COUNT(*) rank 
        FROM IN_buffer x 
        JOIN IN_buffer y 
          ON y.plate = x.plate 
         AND ((y.date < x.date) OR (y.date = x.date AND y.time <= x.time)) 
       GROUP 
          BY x.plate
           , x.date
           , x.time
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.plate
            , x.date
            , x.time
            , COUNT(*) rank 
        FROM OUT_buffer x 
        JOIN OUT_buffer y 
          ON y.plate = x.plate 
         AND ((y.date < x.date) OR (y.date = x.date AND y.time <= x.time)) 
       GROUP 
          BY x.plate
           , x.date
           , x.time
     ) b
    ON b.plate = a.plate 
   AND b.rank = a.rank;

+---------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| plate   | date_in    | time_in  | date_out   | time_out |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 06:07:08 | 2013-12-03 | 06:34:12 |
| HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 07:08:09 | 2013-12-03 | 10:29:40 |
| HN51KTG | 2013-12-03 | 11:25:45 | 2013-12-03 | 16:32:14 |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

However, from your comments, the actual process works like this:

1. INSERT `IN_Buffer` data into `stay`
2. UPDATE `stay` with OUT_Buffer data.

That's easy. Just adapt the query something like the following. Note, I've concatenated date and time in the `stay` table...

```
CREATE TABLE stay
(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Plate VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
, dt_in DATETIME NOT NULL
,dt_out DATETIME NULL);

INSERT INTO stay (plate,dt_in) 
SELECT plate,CONCAT(date,' ',time) FROM IN_Buffer;

UPDATE stay m
  JOIN 
     ( 
     SELECT a.plate
     , a.dt_in
     , b.dt_out
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.plate
            , x.dt_in
            , COUNT(*) rank 
        FROM stay x 
        JOIN stay y 
          ON y.plate = x.plate 
         AND y.dt_in <= x.dt_in 
       GROUP 
          BY x.plate
           , x.dt_in
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.plate
            , CONCAT(x.date,' ',x.time) dt_out
            , COUNT(*) rank 
        FROM OUT_buffer x 
        JOIN OUT_buffer y 
          ON y.plate = x.plate 
         AND ((y.date < x.date) OR (y.date = x.date AND y.time <= x.time)) 
       GROUP 
          BY x.plate
           , dt_out
     ) b
    ON b.plate = a.plate 
   AND b.rank = a.rank
   ) n
  ON n.plate = m.plate
 AND n.dt_in = m.dt_in
 SET m.dt_out = n.dt_out;
```

Comment: Thanks. this is a big step in the right direction. I still need to insert the IN and OUT contents into the tbl_stay separately. I've noticed from adapting your solution here that the entire contents of the buffer gets transferred over, causing duplicate data in tbl_stay. do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: Why 'separately'? Also, while I appreciate that there may not be much you can do about the format of the buffer data, adapting the `stay` table such that date and time are stored as one will terrifically improve performance and ease of use.

Comment: Tbl_stay is also being used for a query of "vehicles on site", which looks for entries within the table that have an IN time but no OUT time. when a vehicle enters, it's entry time is added into one half of the table with an `insert` command, when it exits, the exit time is added into the other half of the table with an `update` command to produce the data format mentioned in the initial question, this data will then get queried to produce reports about duration of stay, etc.

Comment: Oh, OK - but that's not a problem, is it?

Comment: Well, at the moment, this is where my problem lies. I'm trying to adapt the solution you provided to fit into this scenario, which is what i'm struggling on now. If it helps, i'll update my question with the new situation

Comment: See edit, but if it still doesn't fit, then yes. Update your original question.

Comment: I've updated my original post. should provide a bit more information of the current situation an intention.